# Validating String Literal Type with class-validator

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I have this type:

```
export type BranchOperatorRole = 'none' | 'seller' | 'operator' | 'administrator';
```

With which class-validator decorator can I validate that a property has one of those values?

```
import { IsEmail, IsString, Contains } from "class-validator";

export type BranchOperatorRole = 'none' | 'seller' | 'operator' | 'administrator';

export class AddBranchOperatorRequest extends User {

    @IsEmail()
    email: string;

    @Contains(BranchOperatorRole )
    role: BranchOperatorRole;

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't validate by type since Types disappears in runtime. You can create Enum and use `IsEnum` decorator for validation. [Example](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/85)

In your case try something like this:

```js
export enum BranchOperatorRoleEnum = {
  none=1,
  seller=2,
  // other
}

class AddBranchOperatorRequest {
    @IsEnum(BranchOperatorRoleEnum)
    role: BranchOperatorRole;
}
```

Or even with array instead of enum

```js
export type BranchOperatorRole = 'none' | 'seller' | 'operator' | 'administrator';

export const BranchOperatorRoles: BranchOperatorRole[] = [
  'none',
  'seller',
  // other
]

class AddBranchOperatorRequest {
    @IsEnum(BranchOperatorRoles)
    role: BranchOperatorRole;
}
```

Comment: Kinda sill you're doubling your code. Double the hardcoded values. There must be a better way. I believe!

Answer (score 13):

```js
const roles = ['none', 'seller', 'operator', 'administrator'] as const;
export type BranchOperatorRole = typeof roles[number];

export class AddBranchOperatorRequest extends User {

    @IsEmail()
    email: string;

    @IsIn(roles)
    role: BranchOperatorRole;

}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Works without `as const` too, would appreciate some explanation as @AdrianMole suggested!